# how to run a program and get the output without an .exe file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, exe

I need a python program to be called and take the output while another program is running. To do this i created an `.exe` file, but after 2 days I finally realised that, for some reason, the `sklearn` library doesn't work in `.exe` files.
Is there any other way to run a script and get the output that doesn't include an `.exe` file?

Comment: How about creating a bat and run `python your_python_file.py`?

Comment: now it works but i don't know how to pass the input data, can you explain it to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command line, you call your python like this

```
python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

In your python, you get the parameters from the command line by `sys.argv`

```py
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

You will get output

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

`sys.argv` is a list. You call them like `sys.argv[1]`, where `1` could be `0`,`1`,`2` or `3` in this case.